# I'm doing a VB.net Caesar Cipher

Tags: vb.net, encryption

Good day,

i'm having trouble of finishing this homework :<
i'm doing a caesar cipher where the user will have a txt file 
then the program will find the text file and read what's inside of it
then overwrite the text file

so far i'm able to do the code but i'm getting a

index out of range and nullreference exception

here's my code

```
Imports System.IO


Public Class main_form
    Dim x, y, z, str_len As Integer 'where x is a counter for the array
    Dim loc, read(5), write(), str_1, str_2, aa As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub brw_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles brw_btn.Click
        TextBox1.Clear()
        OFD1.ShowDialog()
        TextBox1.Text = OFD1.FileName
        loc = OFD1.FileName
        read = File.ReadAllLines(OFD1.FileName)


    End Sub

    Private Sub enc_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles enc_btn.Click
        'Formula of Caesar's Cipher
        z = 1
        x = 0
        If read(x) <> "" Then

            While read(x) <> ""
                str_2 = ""
                str_1 = read(x)
                str_len = Len(str_1)
                MessageBox.Show(str_2)
                For i As Integer = 0 To str_len - 1
                    y = Asc(Mid(str_1, i + 1, i + 2))
                    y = y + Val(TextBox2.Text)
                    str_2 = str_2 + Chr(y)
                    MessageBox.Show(str_2)
                Next
                MessageBox.Show(str_2)
                write(x) = str_2
                File.AppendAllLines(OFD1.FileName, write(x))

                x += 1
            End While
        Else

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks!

Comment: And where does this exception occur?  Have you stepped through this with the debugger to see what index it's trying to access?

Comment: the index out of range execption occurs when i remove these lines  write(x) = str_2
                File.AppendAllLines(OFD1.FileName, write(x)) 

and hits after rewriting the last  line in my text file

and the other when these lines are in :<

Answer (score 0):

Of course you are getting *out of range exception* because :

```
While read(x) <> ""
    ...
    ...
    x += 1 'if x goes out of range the next loop in while will access read(x <-out of range) 
End While
```

You have to insert

```
While read(x) <> ""
    ...
    ...
    x += 1
    If x >= read.Length
        Exit While
    End If
End While
```

Also:

```
Dim write() as String
...
write(x) = str_2 '<-write is used un initialized, null reference exception
```

Change `write() to write` or:

```
Private Sub enc_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles enc_btn.Click
    ReDim write(read.Length) '<---
    z = 1
    x = 0
    If read(x) <> "" Then
    ...
    ...
```

Valter